# how to extract a sample from dpfp template (vb 2010 .net 4.0)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, fingerprint

i am finished in saving a fingeprint template to database ...

and this is my code in converting sample to byte

While reader.Read

```
                        Dim memory As IO.MemoryStream
                        Dim fbytes As Byte()
                        Dim templ8te As New DPFP.Template


                        If Not reader("emp_FP").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                            fbytes = reader("emp_FP")
                            memory = New IO.MemoryStream(fbytes)
                            templ8te.DeSerialize(memory)
                            verificator.Verify(vf, templ8te, result)
                        End If


                        If result.Verified Then
                            Exit While
                        End If

                        If Not reader("Left_Thumb").Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
                            Dim fbytes2 As Byte()
                            fbytes2 = reader("Left_Thumb")
                            memory = New IO.MemoryStream(fbytes2)
                            templ8te.DeSerialize(memory)
                            verificator.Verify(vf, templ8te, result)
                        End If

                        If result.Verified Then
                            Exit While
                        End If

                    End While
```

but now i need to retrieve the template and extract a sample from the template and display it

as a bitmap in crystal report i am using also dataset

i dont know what to do

i am stuck at this code

```
    Dim bitmap As Bitmap = Nothing
    Dim ex As DPFP.Processing.FeatureExtraction
    Dim convertor As New DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion
    Dim fbyte As Byte() = set2.Tables(0).DefaultView.Item(0).Item(1)
    Dim stream As IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream(fbyte)
    a.DeSerialize(stream)
```

i just retrieved the template from the database

need your help guys

please please

by the way this is for my thesis

Comment: You need to try something yourself first, and, when you run into a difficulty, you can ask a specific question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand by the [**official API reference**](http://www.crossmatch.com/uploadedFiles/Support/Reference_Material/Guides/SDK_Guides/One-Touch-for-Windows-.NET-Developer-Guide.pdf), only the `DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion` class have a method to convert a `Sample` to a `Bitmap`

**DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion Class**

```
ConvertToPicture(Sample, ref Bitmap)
```

**Syntax**

```
public Bitmap ConvertToPicture(
Sample Sample,
ref Bitmap Bitmap
)
```

**Parameters**

- **Sample** *A DPFP.Sample object*
- **Bitmap** *Variable that receives and contains an image in bitmap file format and scales the
  image to a specified bitmap size, if provided*

**Return Value**

> Returns a bitmap that receives and contains an image in bitmap file
>   format.

Comment: Sir, My question is how to extract sample from a template, the template is retrieved from the database

Comment: You are right, I saw that I found only a method to convert by a Sample, so the API does't have a native method to convert by a Template

Comment: i agree with you sir, i also reviewed the developer guide 

can't find anything for my problem

Answer (score 0):

i just came up of solution guys added one column in my table and use it for storing dpfp samples

the process of saving and retrieving sample is the same

this is my final code

Dim sample As New DPFP.Sample

```
    Dim bitmap As Bitmap = Nothing

    Dim fbyte As Byte() = set2.Tables(0).DefaultView.Item(0).Item(1)
    Dim stream As IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream(fbyte)

    sample.DeSerialize(stream)

    Dim convertor As New DPFP.Capture.SampleConversion
    convertor.ConvertToPicture(sample, bitmap)
    Dim con As New ImageConverter
    Dim bytes As Byte() = DirectCast(con.ConvertTo(bitmap, GetType(Byte())), Byte())

    datarow("Right_FP_Sample") = bytes
    sets.Bio.AddBioRow(datarow)
```

I hope it will also help other people